# MVC Disable EditFor automatic-fill

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have recently started using MVC, and stumbled upon a problem.

So, I have a user model, which contains some variables like ID, UserName, Password, and they all correspont do a database table, which MVC completely handles.

I now have a password edit page, with a password text box, and a confirm password text box, like this:

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
        @Html.Password("passwordConfirmation")
    </div>
```

So, that works out all fine, it has 2 text boxes next to eachother.

Now here's my problem: I don't want the first password text box to be automatically filled with the data from the "Password" variable that is in the model passed along with the page.

Ofcourse there's the "hackish" way of doing it, where you just create a regular password box, and then get it's value later (@Html.Password("password")),
but I want to know if there's an official way of telling MVC NOT to auto-fill in the text/password box.

Comment: Are you passing view models to the views or your models directly? Maybe I don't fully understand the problem, but maybe just don't populate the password property on the model passed to the view.

Comment: The controller is passing the user model to the view. The user model has a password in it, that has been set, that password is being printed into the views text box. This is what I am trying to prevent.

Answer (score 1):

You could try applying the `autocomplete="off"` attribute to your password field:

```
@Html.PasswordFor(x => x.PasswordConfirmation, new { autocomplete = "off" })
```

Note that this is a non-standard attribute and might break HTML validation but most browsers respect it.

Also you should make sure that you are not setting any value on your view model for the `PasswordConfirmation` property inside the controller action.

Comment: Won't that just add an attribute to the outputted HTML? OP wants to prevent the Password value in the model from being displayed on the page.

Comment: Yes, but he showed the use of `PasswordFor` to ensure type=password.  Password boxes aren't auto-filled with model data the same way textboxes are.  Adding autocomplete=off doesn't solve the problem, but is often used on password reset forms so your browser doesn't prefill.

Comment: Agreed, Keith, autocomplete is just a HTML property (not to mention non standardized), and should not have to do anything to do with the text MVC puts into the text box.

Comment: @René Sackers, the text *MVC puts in* is controlled by the value of the `Password` and `PasswordConfirmation` properties on your view model. As I said in my answer you could set it to an empty string in this action. Obviously no matter what value you set it to, if the client browser is configured to remember passwords, etc... over which you have no control from the server side, the password field will be prefilled automatically. To avoid this you could use the `autocomplete` attribute. I agree that it is not standard but in this situation it could be used and it might solve your issue.

Comment: Yes, I see Darin, now I get what you mean with the autocomplete attribute. However, as I asked in my question, I was wondering if there was a actual MVC property or whatever to not let it put the value into the text box. Without doing stuff like setting the password to nothing before passing it.

Comment: @René Sackers, when you inspect the generated HTML is there a value for the password field?

Comment: Yes, it does. If the password wasn't encrypted, you could pull it from the value="" property in the site's source.